# Sorting in Amazon SimpleDB not working

Tags: c#, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-simpledb

I am trying to fetch the records from amazon simple db . I found this article [Sorting - Amazon SimpleDB](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonSimpleDB/latest/DeveloperGuide/SortingDataSelect.html) which describes sorting in amazon SimpleDB. Example mentioned in article as below

```
select * from mydomain where Year = '2007' intersection Author is not null order by Author desc
```

I have created similar query to fetch the result as below

```
SELECT * FROM `TABLE` where  DEPT='COMPUTER' and NAME like 'mid%' intersection SAL is not null order by SAL desc
```

It's giving me result but it's not in descending order

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All values in `Amazon SimpleDB` are stored as `UTF-8 strings`. All attribute comparisons are done `lexicographically`. E.g. Suppose you have following `values` -

```
1
20
8
40
11
12
```

After applying `asc` `sorting` you will get following from `Amazon SimpleDB` -

```
1
11
12
20
40
8
```

Solution: `Zero-Padding` i.e. number 2 will be represented as "02"

```
001
020
008
040
011
012
```

Now you will get from `Amazon SimpleDB`:

```
001
008
011
012
020
040
```

For more details please refer the [link](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/Amazon-SimpleDB/1232).

Comment: –Is there any specific command which will help to    replace the SAL attribute with zero-padding for ALL ITEMS in the domain ?

Comment: There is no such command supported by Amazon SimpleDB which will replace values into zero-padding.

Comment: `SDBExplorer` supports `Export` in `CSV` and `Import` from `My-Sql` or `CSV`. One way to achive that is -  1. You need to `Export` your `domain` into `CSV`. 2. Remove all columns except `itemName()` and `SAL` from the `exported CSV`. 3. Update all values of `SAL` columns  (sorry but you need to find a way which replace your values with zero-padding in exported file) 4. Once it done, `Import` back into `domain` with `Replace = True` so it will `overwrite all` existing values.

Comment: What I am trying to say here is - `Amazon SimpleDB` does not support so you can `Export` your data outside from `Amazon SimpleDB`, modify it according to your need and `Import` Back into `Amazon SimpleDB`.

Comment: is there any way to get the last item's  ITEMNAME  from simpleDB.